# Playwright with launch_persistent_context and executablePath

Tags: python, playwright

I am really hoping for some help. Have been fighting this for quite some time now. I have a working script, however if I use the native Firefox or native Chrome, the version that comes with Playwright I easily get caught by any security. I must use the version that I have installed, to do so I do:

```
        browser = await p.firefox.launch_persistent_context(
        executable_path = r"C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe",
    user_data_dir=r"C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/james",
        headless=False)
        page = await browser.new_page()
        await page.goto("http://playwright.dev")
```

Now it opens the correct .exe, however page does not work. I cannot open a new page, I cannot do page.goto. Nothing really works. What is going on here?

I tried to do other functions, but the browser does not respond to ANY commands.